# Uncaught Error: Script error for lib для библиотеки под node

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs

Для функционала сайта мне понадобилось использовать `node.js`-библиотеку [xlsx-chart](https://github.com/objectum/xlsx-chart), и я не знаю, как её правильно подключить. В файле `static/js/init.js` я пишу:

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: 'static',
    paths: {
        'jquery': 'libs/jquery/dist/jquery.min',
        'jquery.maskedinput': 'libs/jquery.maskedinput/dist/jquery.maskedinput.min',
        'bootstrap': 'libs/bootswatch-dist/js/bootstrap.min',
        'chart': '../node_modules/xlsx-chart/chart' // <-- not at static but at node_modules
    }
```

В консоли браузера я получаю ошибку:

```
Uncaught Error: Script error for "chart"
```

Вызываю библиотеку так:

```
require(['chart'], function(XLSXChart){ 
    debugger;
```

Дебаггер не включается. Как правильно подключить нужную библиотеку?

**Upd.**

Не может ли это быть связано с тем, что сайт обращается на сервер к python, а тут ещё серверный node.js пытаются подключить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка связана с тем, что сайты, работающие на питоне, обращаются к url, описанным в urls.py, а библиотека, работающая на node.js, загружается по своему url, который в urls.py не задан.

P.S. Я не знаю, можно ли заставить работать связку python + node.js, это уже не относится к данному вопросу.